# JavaScript for updating shopping cart subtotal

Tags: javascript, html-table, shopping-cart

I have a problem with the following JavaScript code. It has an error alert said that table value is undefined. I'm trying to update the subtotal in each row by calculate `price * qty`.

```
function updateSubtotal() {
       var subTotal = 0;
       var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table").rows;
       var r = this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
       var j = document.getElementsByTagName(".price").cellIndex;
       var s = document.getElementsByTagName(".subtotal").cellIndex;
       var price = tables[r].cells[j].value;
       var quantity = document.getElementsByTagName("input").value;
       var subAmount = price * quantity;
       subTotal += Number(subAmount);
       // set total for the row
       document.getElementsByTagName('table').rows[r].cells[s].innerHTML = '$' + subTotal.toFixed(2);
       }
     updateTotal();
}
```

The original code that I tried to update:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">


    window.onload = setupCart;

    function setupCart() {
      var qtyInputs = document.querySelectorAll( 'input' );
      for ( var i = 0; i < qtyInputs.length; i++ ) {
        qtyInputs[ i ].oninput = updateSubtotal;
      }
      updateTotal();
    }



    function updateTotal() {
      var total = 0;
      var subTotals = document.querySelectorAll( '.subtotal' );
      for ( var i = 0; i < subTotals.length; i++ ) {
        var amount = subTotals[ i ].innerHTML.match( /[0-9]+.[0-9]+/ );
        total += Number( amount );
      }
      document.querySelector( '#total' ).innerHTML = '$' + total.toFixed( 2 );
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>


  ><table>
    ><tr>
      ><th>Description</th>
      ><th>Each</th>
      ><th>Qty</th>
      ><th>subtotal</th>
    ></tr>

    <tr class="item">
      <td class="description"><a href=""><img src="red-shirt.jpg" alt="" />Red Crew Neck T-Shirt</a></td>
      <td class="price">$15.00</td>
      <td><input type="number" value="1" min="0" /></td>
      <td class="subtotal">$15.00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="item">
      <td class="description"><a href=""><img src="tropical-shirt.jpg" alt="" />Blue Tropical Floral Print T-Shirt</a></td>
      <td class="price">$25.00</td>
      <td><input type="number" value="1" min="0" /></td>
      <td class="subtotal">$25.00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="item">
      <td class="description"><a href=""><img src="black-sneakers.jpg" alt="" />Black Canvas Lace Up Sneakers</a></td>
      <td class="price">$35.00</td>
      <td><input type="number" value="1" min="0" /></td>
      <td class="subtotal">$35.00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="item">
      <td class="description"><a href=""><img src="black-grey-jacket.jpg" alt="" />Black and Grey Hooded Jacket</a></td>
      <td class="price">$40.00</td>
      <td><input type="number" value="1" min="0" /></td>
      <td class="subtotal">$40.00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="item">
      <td class="description"><a href=""><img src="black-sunglasses.jpg" alt="" />Black Retro Sunglasses</a></td>
      <td class="price">$15.00</td>
      <td><input type="number" value="1" min="0" /></td>
      <td class="subtotal">$15.00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="cart-summary">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <th>Total:</th>
      <td id="total"></td>
    </tr>

  </table>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.getElementsByTagName()` function returns a NodeList object. If you want the first `<table>` on the page, you'd use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows ...
```

It would be better to fetch it just once at the start of the function:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
```

to avoid having to re-traverse the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because document.getElementsByTagName doesn't return an element but a list of elements... you have to access the node you need like this document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows